# AR drone autonomy in armhf

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried the [following description](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone)  to install ar drone autonomy package in beagle bone black.

I am using Ubuntu arm 12.04 in BBB and ROS hydro.

my steps are :

```
roscd
git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy.git
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_autonomy
cd ardrone_autonomy
./build_sdk.sh
```

and shows

```
Checking required Ubuntu packages ...
You should install the following packages to compile the AR.Drone SDK with Ubuntu:
 
  daemontools : Mandatory to build the AR.Drone project on Ubuntu
  libsdl1.2-dev
  libgtk2.0-dev
  libxml2-dev
  libudev-dev
  libiw-dev 

Do you want to install them now [y/n] ?
y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-dev (>= 2:1.0.0-6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxinerama-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxi-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 1:1.2.99)
                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxfixes-dev (>= 1:3.0.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcomposite-dev (>= 1:0.2.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxdamage-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxml2-utils but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: gir1.2-gtk-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
 libpython3.2 : Depends: python3.2 (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-help : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libsdl1.2debian (= 1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libasound2-dev
                 Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcaca-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libxau-dev : Depends: x11proto-core-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
make[1]: *** [checkpackages] Error 100
make: *** [all] Error 2
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:/opt/ros/hydro/ardrone_autonomy$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202901/ar-drone-autonomy-in-armhf/) by [telephus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21609/telephus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the solution is written in the error output.

> Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages

---

Originally posted by [CameronVee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21616/cameronvee/) with karma: 11 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have missing dependencies. I don't know if the ardrone has been tested on armhf platforms. You need to audit all the dependencies recursively and make sure they are available from your sources.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1